# Open Excel attachment using Outlook 2010

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2010, outlook-2010

I am trying to open an Excel attachment using an Outlook rule. I am using the below VBA to do this:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim FileName As String

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsx") Then
        FileName = "S:\Projects\" & objAtt
        objAtt.SaveAsFile FileName
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Application.Visible = True
        xlApp.Application.EnableEvents = False
        x1App.Workbooks.Open FileName
    End If

    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
MsgBox ("DONE")

End Sub
```

It opens the Excel application, however on the open filename line, it shuts the Excel application and jumps out of the code.

Also please let me know if I am doing this in an overly complicated way!

Comment: remove the `.Application` parts - `xlApp.Visible = True`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you pass a wrong filepath to the Open method:

```
 FileName = "S:\Projects\" & objAtt
```

Try to use the [DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869359(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Attachment class.

```
 FileName = "S:\Projects\" & objAtt.DisplayName
```

Also make sure that you have sufficient privileges for writing on the S drive and can access it any time. Try to specify any local drive.

Comment: Thanks for that, have added in the display name portion, but doesn't seem to have solved it. It is able to save down the file fine, but then it kicks out when I try and open it. 
That is what is the weird bit, it doesn't give me any errors, it just jumps out of the code at this line without saying why...

     'x1App.Workbooks.Open FileName'

Comment: What was the actual file name?

Comment: The actual file name is: "Valuation: NOTES DAILY (Internal Use Only)_20150904.xlsx" with the date changing.

Is it normal for the vba to just end without any sort of debugging? I haven't seen that before...

Comment: I mean the FileName value in the code, i.e. including a file path?

Comment: Yeah I define it in the code above? I have amended it to
     'FileName = "\\oak\eu\shared\Projects\SCI\Luke\Projects & Ad Hoc Work\Outlook vba\" & objAtt.DisplayName'

Comment: In fact I have gone through the code line by line again, using different filepaths (currently using: `C:\Users\lbetham\Downloads\` )and each time get the same outcome. It opens the excel application, and then when it gets to the line to open the workbook, it closes the excel application it has just opened and jumps out of the code without debugging. Any other suggestions as to what might be happening?     @EugeneAstafeiv